# I have an error while uploading csv file

Tags: php, csv

I can read the csv file  form localhost, Once I move to online It show's error
Warning: fopen(boo1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ashishco/public_html/group/fetchCsv.php on line 28,

I don't know how to give path.

```
<?php
include("includes/connection.php");
include("includes/mail.php");
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))

        {

    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
    //echo $ext=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,"."),(strlen($filename)-strrpos($filename,".")));

    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
      `MId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Batch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `Department` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `RegisterNo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `EmailId` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
      `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `MobileNo` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`MId`)
    )");
     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             $count=1;
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                //print_r($emapData);
                if($count>1)
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT into myTable(Batch,Department,RegisterNo,Name,EmailId,Password,MobileNo) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]')";
                    //echo $sql; 
                    mysql_query($sql);
                }
                $count++;
             }

         //die();
         fclose($file);
         echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported";

             fnSendMail();

}

    else
    {
    echo "Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What is your directory structure? your code will work if you have csv and fetchCsv.php  file in same location.

Comment: on server  i will put everything in group folder, i am asking where do i give the path, i have given the path like this $filename="group/$_FILES["file"]["name"]"; it is showing same error, i am not sure about where  i give path

Answer (score 0):

you should give your path like this

```
$file = fopen("/ your path/".$filename, "r");
```

Suppose your csv file have path as  /home/group/file.csv and your php file have path as /home/yourphp.php then you will call as

```
$file = fopen("/group/".$filename, "r");
```

in your case  just use as

```
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
```

Comment: i  have implemented your code.echo it and gave exit it is showing boo1.csv
Warning: fopen(/group/boo1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ashishco/public_html/group/fetchCsv.php on line 24  Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ashishco/public_html/group/fetchCsv.php on line 28

Comment: Now i have give the path to entire location $file = fopen("http://www.ashishcomputerworld.com/group/".$filename, "r");
it is showing Warning: fopen(http://www.ashishcomputerworld.com/group/boo1.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /home/ashishco/public_html/group/fetchCsv.php on line 24

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ashishco/public_html/group/fetchCsv.php on line 28

Comment: thanks a lot to every one, i got the  solution with this $file = fopen($filename, "r"); it working fine